# Change of basis from one linear mapping to another

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

I have this PDE which looks like this $\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}= A\vec{x}+B\vec{x}$

Where $A$ and $B$ are both $n\times n$ matrices, and $\vec{x}$ is a state vector.

Without making this too complicated I have a $141\times29$ matrix showing the evolved state of $\vec{x}$ for $29$ time steps, represented in the basis of eigenvectors from matrix $A$.  Lets call this $141\times29$ matrix --**Solution**--

I didn't solve the system myself, and don't know how to set up the equation to get **Solution** in the basis of eigenvectors from matrix $B$ so I'm trying to do a change of basis, in order to get **Solution** in terms of the eigenvectors of matrix $B$.

I know both matrix $A$ and $B$ as then I know their eigenvectors

```
EigA = {valA, vecA} = Eigensystem[N[A]];
EigB = {valB, vecB} = Eigensystem[N[B]];
SolutionB = 
Table[Abs[Sum[Solution[[i, t]]*vecA[[m]].vecB[[i]], {i, 1, 141}]], {m, 1, 141}, {t, 1, 29];
```

But when I get my result the solution doesn't look correct according to myself and all my friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So is what you want just the change of basis from $A$ to $B$?  If so, then the mathematical operation you want is probably that described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628061/how-to-construct-change-of-basis-matrix), which might be implemented as

```
Inverse[Transpose@Eigenvectors@matrixB].Transpose@Eigenvectors@matrixA
```

which could then be `Map`ped across your Solution matrix